# How to get Retina display iPad simulator in XCode 4.2, Mac OS 10.6.8 (Snow Loepard)

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, xcode4.2, ios-simulator

i'v been looking to kick start my app development for the new iPad(iPad-3). But i could not find a place where i can download/update my XCode inorder to get the **retina display simulator**. Apple released **XCode 4.3.1 with iOS 5.1 SDK**. But that requires Mac OS 10.7.3(Lion). Is it **mandatory** for me to **upgrade** myself to Lion in order to start developing apps for the retina display iPad or can i get the same in Snow Leopard???

Comment: I think you'll have to upgrade. Apple does not believe in supporting "old" software, and certainly not for their developer toolchain. iBooks Author is Lion-only, too, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried installing the same from Snow leopard and failed with error "Xcode can't be installed on Macintosh HD because Mac OS X version 10.7.3 or later is required."

So updated to Lion 10.7.3 and took Xcode 4.3.1 from Mac App Store which was released on 7th March 2012.

Yes, you have to upgrade to Lion.

Comment: +1 dude. So do you mean to say that we can not develop apps for retina display iPad on Snow Leopard ??

Comment: I also understand that XCode 4.3.1 requires Lion. But is there any equivalent version for Snow Leopard as well???

Comment: I haven't tried this, try for this beta [link](http://9to5mac.com/2011/11/28/apple-seeds-first-ios-5-1-beta-xcode-4-3-beta/)

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same issue and found this link that could be interesting:
http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/100229-snow-leopard-sdk-5-1-a.html

Not sure if you can submit your apps to the apple store when they are built this way.