# I need a version of iOS Simulator that includes iPad retina display

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I'm trying to get a copy of the iOS simulator that includes an iPad retina display. I followed the advice [on this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9679008/how-to-get-retina-display-ipad-simulator-in-xcode-4-2-mac-os-10-6-8-snow-loepa), downloading the latest copy of Xcode: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/

However, having downloaded that, it didn't actually update the simulator, which still lacks support for the retina display for iPad. Am I missing something?

Comment: By the way, I am running Lion so that's not the issue.

Comment: Did you actually start the Xcode version that is inside your Application folder? If you just used the Xcode icon that is in your dock you are still launching Xcode 4.2 from the `/Developer` folder. Xcode 4.3 and up is a single .app file inside `/Application`. And of course the simulator is now part of that app bundle too. Don't use the old icons you kept in the dock with older Xcode version

Comment: OK, that helps. Yes, I was launching the old Xcode. Now that I've tracked down the new one, and have confirmed that it's 4.3.2, I'm not clear how to get to the simulator. I find no mention of it in any documentation. What's the secret?

Comment: The simulator is included with 4.3.2 but by default it will not use the retina simulator. (as it doesn't fit on most screens) you can switch to it from within the simulator by going to the navigation bar (Finder bar what ever you want to call it) and clicking HARDWARE>>DEVICE>>IPAD(RETINA)

Comment: My biggest problem is actually tracking down the simulator within XCode 4.3.2. I've found something called "Instruments" which makes mention of an iOS simulator. However, the simulator is not what it was in previous versions where you could simply launch apps or Safari and test. "Instruments" doesn't have any of that. Is it still possible to simulate iOS as was done on the previous version of XCode? If so, what exact menu commands take me from XCode to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've found the answer, and considering there is zero documentation, I'm amazed that anyone else was ever able to find the simulator. Here's how you get there:

1. Right-click on the Xcode file and select Show Package Contents
2. Go Contents --> Developer --> Platforms --> iPhoneSimulator.platform
   --> Developer --> Applications --> iOS Simulator

Intuitive, huh?

Why Apple decided to bury what is arguably the most used tool in the entire iOS SDK is something I will probably never know.

Comment: Mainly because they want you to go through XCode to open the simulator.  I have tried this just to look at mobile websites through the simulator.  Pain to find and yes there is zero documentation on the Apple website. They need to hire someone to explain the documentation.  So 'intuitive' right?  Not so as they claim their products are.